# Python string length recursion

Tags: python, string, recursion, string-length

I'm blanking out trying to write a simple function to count the string length recursively.

I can do sums, fibonacci, and factorial easy but I'm trying to create the simplest function with only one parameter, I don't like having a second just as a counter index..

Can any post something small for me?

Comment: I don't think you can do it using only one parameter, unless you're talking about global variables.

Comment: @Dean: Of course you can. You just have to do *tons* of copying and non-tail recursion (not that tail recursion would help, it's not optimized away). But then again, you don't write this kind of code because of some real-world problem but as an exercise.

Comment: Sure you can -- all you need are string slicing, a return value, and addition. The base case is that the length of an empty string is zero. Hesitant to say more about something that smells like homework.

Comment: As soon as I posted this it clicked that you could do it like Alberteddu's answer.

Comment: Not homework. This would be in some intro class ha. Thanks Alberteddu!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def recursiveLength(theString):
    if theString == '': return 0
    return 1 + recursiveLength(theString[1:])
```

Comment: `is` tests identity not equality. It works, but relies on an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

This does it:

```
def length(s):
    return 0 if s == '' else 1 + length(s[:-1])

print length('hello world') # prints 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional haskell style

```
       >>> def RecListValue(list_value):
               return type(list_value) in [list,str,tuple] and list_value and    1+RecListValue(list_value[1:]) or 0
       >>> example_struct  = [range(10), ("one",)*12, "simple string", 12]       
       >>> map(RecListValue, example_struct)
           [10, 12, 13, 0]
       >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be tail-recursive:

```
def strlen(s):
  if s == '':
    return 0
  return 1 + strlen(s[1:])
```

It's pretty inefficient though.